# Share data from one Kubernetes container to another inside same pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have two containers inside my Pod:

- Container A based on my own Dockerfile. Inside this Dockerfile, there is  `COPY ./files /my-files` command. This image is inside my GitLab Docker registry.
- Container B based on image from hub.docker.com.

I'd like to share data from Container A that are stored inside /my-files to Container B. I thought that I need to create a `volume` (it's not a persisted data) inside this pod and `volumeMounts` to the container.

Unfortunately when I add `volumeMounts` to Container A with `mountPath: /my-files` this directory is emptied and there are no files that were added when an image was created.

What should I do to keep this data and share it with Container B.

This is part of my Deployment.yaml file:

```
containers:
- name: Container-A
  image: "my-gitlab-registry/my-image-a-with-copied-files"
  volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /my-files
- name: Container-B
  image: "some-public-image"
  volumeMounts:
  - name: shared-data
    mountPath: /files-from-container-a

volumes:
- name: shared-data
  emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: When you mount inside a k8s container, the mounted volume will "hide" anything that already existed in that location. What kind of data is this? It sounds like either you need to create a configmap for it, or you need to copy it into both images before creating the pod & containers.

Comment: I'm creating a PHP app using PHP-FPM and Apache. The first container is based on PHP-FPM. I copy all data of application inside /var/www/html. The second one is Apache pointing to FPM. But both containers need same files inside /var/www/html directory.
It's sad, that there is no "flag" telling to keep those files and copy inside mounted volume.

Comment: Are you just wanting Apache to act as a reverse proxy for PHP-FPM? If so, the thing to do would be to use port mappings to let Apache talk to your PHP container, and not share any content directly. Your Apache container would get it's config from a configmap, and then make requests directly to your app container on some arbitrary port, like `8080`.

Comment: If you really need to share static content between two containers, you need to either build that content into both images (in which case they can potentially share layers behind the scenes), or store that content in some other system like an S3 bucket, and then map that into your containers via volume mounts.

Answer (score 7):

A ugly hack, use init container, to copy data into emptyDir volume, then mount volume in 2nd container.

```
  initContainers:
    - name: init-config-data-copy-wait
      image: datacontainer
      command:
        - sh
        - "-ce"
        - |
          set -ex
          cp -r /src-data/* /dst-data/
          ls /dst-data/
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /dst-data
          name: dst-data-volume

  volumes:
    - name: dst-data-volume
      emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: By the way, it's not that ugly, it makes sense. For example, if you update files in the source image, you don't need to perform any manual installation actions, you just restart the pod and it syncs itself.

Comment: Great! intContainer command make `emptyDir` volumes not emty any more!